# Javascript jQuery error firing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer

Here is the code and the error message:

> Webpage error details
>
> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64;
>   Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR
>   3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2) Timestamp: Wed, 18 Jan 2012 20:26:33 UTC
>
> Message: Unexpected call to method or property access. Line: 3 Char:
>   31959 Code: 0 URI:
>   https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js

And the Jquery Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.small-list-items-pagination li a').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: '/Noticias/FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage',
                    data: "page=" + $(this).text(),
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('.small-list-items li').remove();

                        $.each(data, function(i, val){
                            $(".small-list-items").append('<li>' +
                                '<img src="' + val.ImagenChicaUrl + '" alt="' + val.Descripcion + '"/>' +
                                '<a href="#">' + val.FechaDePublicacion + '</a>' +
                                '<p>' + val.Descripcion + '</p>' +
                                 '<div class="horizontal-line"></div>' +
                            '</li>');
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (obj) {
                        alert("bad!");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Any ideas what's wrong? This works great in Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome.

This line:

```
'@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")'
```

Actually compiles to:

```
'/Noticias/FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage'
```

Comment: What does `@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")` output?

Comment: Can you change "@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")" to '@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")'

Comment: @SKS: It's still firing the same error.

Comment: Is it going inside your success call back method? Can you set some alert to narrow down?

Comment: IE croaks on any single error so I can't tell when it's firing. But the error message that prompts up says the line and the error is within the jQuery file itself. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: Sometimes it happens when you forgot to add some link reference. Check, if everything is included and what is of the same importance whether everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the nested double quotes, although i cant beleive other browsers let you get away with that:

```
url: "@Url.Action('FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage', 'Noticias')",
```

--OR--

```
url: '@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")',
```

or are you trying:

```
url: "@Url.Action("+FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage+", "+Noticias+")",
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I believe that `@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")` will be parsed by ASP to a string so the browser won't ever see this code.

Comment: This line: `'@Url.Action("FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage", "Noticias")'` Actually compiles to: `'/Noticias/FetchMiniNoticiasFromPage'`